# c++ compilation database, why not?

Tags: c++, build

It is interesting for me, why for modern c++ compilers
like `gcc`, `clang` or `cl.exe` (MS) and with modern build
tools like `ninja`, `wtf`, `scons` etc. we still
have to manage precompiled headers by hands?

Why not, for example, during build create for headers database
like `key`(`modification date`, `additional to system defines`, `compiler version`)->data(`AST`), and use during project build?

From the first sight this database should increase time of compilation,
and remove need for developer to manual managing precompiled headers,

but for some reason this is not implemented, and I wonder why?

Too much efforts with small benefits?

**Update:**

I found [mail in clang dev list](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-dev/2015-September/045082.html) about `NetBeans` IDE (for `c++`):

> What we had to made as tradeoff: Parse headers "minimal amount of
>   times" So, we have introduced smth like "chained PCHs" long time ago.
>   It allows to reuse what was parsed in the context of one translation
>   unit for  parsing other translation units if "controling macro" for
>   header check says "ok"  to reuse (so, one header sometimes has several
>   versions of PCH states)

But this about `IDE` parser, not compiler, as I know the most `IDE` use light version of `c++` parser, and I can not found correspoding feature in `sun c++ compiler`.

Comment: If it interests you that much, maybe you can make it your personal project -- open source or otherwise.

Comment: @RSahu I think that there are some pitfalls here, because if no one pitfall, somebody already implement this. And so it is interesting to me to know what is pitfalls are.

Comment: In a sense, you are suggesting to have `.pch` files similarly to `.obj` files. Why not, unless managing their dependencies might be way more complex.

Comment: @A.S.H let's say we work only with header contains `#pragma once` or analog, why then dependency tracking should be more complex?

Comment: `#pragma once` works fine when a translation unit includes `file1.h` and `file2.h` which itself includes `file1.h`. Fine, but, when precompiling `file2.h`, you dont know if you have to assume that `file1.h` is already included in the translation unit or not. This might be not a problem, but i am just having some first thought. Moreover, think about the same question when you have circular inclusion between header files. This question seems not trivial indeed.

Comment: @A.S.H may be I not understand something, but current file `build systems` already solving such task? For example, let you have `file1.c` which include `file1.h`, and `file1.h` include `file2.h`, then you if you modify `file2.h` `file1.c` was recompile, and if no one else include `file2.h` explicity or implicity then nobody else was recompiled. In our case we also need recompile `file1.h`, but I didn't see why not apply already existing tracking dependency algorithm?

Comment: I tend to think that what you suggest should be feasible after all. The question is, is it worth the additional complexity and dependency management. I don't feel myself well-placed to answer such a question, it requires much investigation from IDE developers. Thumbs up for raising it though, I hope we can get a comprehensive answer by specialists.

Comment: @user - If `file1.h` includes `file2.h` and you add or remove a macro in `file2.h`, that might change the whole meaning of `file1.h`.

Comment: @BoPersson yes, that's why in my imaginary database part key is additional to system defines, any way in that case the suitable `.(cpp|cc|cxx|C)` files should be rebuild anyway, and in the most cases `file2.h` would be parsed twice and more, so we gain performance.